# How to avoid page load event when switching to landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout

When my application switches from portrait mode to landscape mode, the page load happens again. How can we avoid this? In an android application, the page load event is equal to asp.net pageload, can we avoid page load again in android application like that?

Answer (score 1):

Add in your Manifest file inside the activity tag `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

Comment: If my answer works for you, you can check my answer so that it can help future users also. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use can use these functions:

1.`onSaveInstanceState()` or

2.`onRetainConfigurationChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

1. in your manifest file , in which activity u want to stop page load just give

   `android:configChanges="orientation"`